# Opportunity List View Filter By Owner Is Null

Tags: list-view, bug, platform-bug

This seems like a bug as I am not sure how this is possible...I am looking back at a saved list view for Opportunity and the Filter By Owner radio buttons are empty. Typically when creating a list view one of these buttons are default selected. How and why would this be able to save with none of the radio buttons selected? Is there a way to query to see if it is selected on the backend and maybe just the front end is not displaying correctly?

[image]